# get current value input field quantity Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, woocommerce, product-quantity

there is any way in php to get the current value of quantity input of Woocommerce ?

I mean this field :

[image]

I need to get in this case 10 and output it.
How can I do that please?

Thanks

Comment: You need to capture the value with javascript and send it to your php script

Comment: post more of your php and more detail because this is quite a vauge request

Comment: at what exact moment do you need to do that (before/after clicking acquista?)?

Answer (score 1):

I resolve install this plugin : https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-min-max-quantity-limit/

with this I can get the min and max value for each product.
I use the code inside :

```
$max = get_post_meta($product->id, '_wc_mmax_max', true);
$min = get_post_meta($product->id, '_wc_mmax_min', true);
```

the full code is :

```
// we are going to hook this on priority 31, so that it would display below add to cart button.
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_total_product_price', 31);

function woocommerce_total_product_price() {

    global $woocommerce, $product;
    $max = get_post_meta($product->id, '_wc_mmax_max', true);
    $min = get_post_meta($product->id, '_wc_mmax_min', true);

    echo sprintf('<div id="product_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;display:none">%s %s</div>', __('Prezzo Prodotto :', 'woocommerce'), '<span class="price">' . $product->get_price() . '</span>');
    echo sprintf('<div id="cart_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;display:none">%s %s</div>', __('Totale Carrello :', 'woocommerce'), '<span class="price">' . $product->get_price() . '</span>');

    $moltiplicazione_prodotto = $product->get_price() * $max;
    $moltiplicazione_prodotto = number_format($moltiplicazione_prodotto, 2, '.', '');
    echo sprintf('<div id="prodotti_quantity" style="margin-bottom:20px;">%s %s</div>', __('Prezzo Prodotto :', 'woocommerce'), '<span class="price">' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . $moltiplicazione_prodotto . '</span>');
    ?>
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
                current_cart_total = <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total; ?>,
                currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

        var quantita_iniziale = $('[name=quantity]').val();
        $('#prodotti_quantity').html(this.value);

        console.log("quantita iniziale", this.value);

        $('[name=quantity]').change(function () {
            if (!(this.value < 1)) {

                var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value),
                cart_total = parseFloat(product_total + current_cart_total);

                $('#product_total_price .price').html(currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
                $('#cart_total_price .price').html(currency + cart_total.toFixed(2));
                if(this.value){
                $('#prodotti_quantity').html(this.value).hide();  
                }


            }
            $('#product_total_price,#cart_total_price').toggle(!(this.value <= 1));
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
}
```